# "Could not load library WinHvPlatform.dll" when running the Android SDK emulator on Windows 10

Tags: android-emulator

When I run the emulator on Windows the following error appears:

```
1:58 PM Emulator: C:\Users\KotlinPc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-i386.exe: Could not load library WinHvPlatform.dll.
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Given that I tried all possible answers in stackoverflow but not working for me.

Comment: Not sure what the results of this were, but have have run a Windows update of late? What output are you getting when you run this: `ANDROID_SDK\emulator\emulator.exe -avd AVDNAME -verbose ?`

Comment: Does the file `WinHvPlatform.dll` exist on your system. It should be present two times in the Windows folder (`C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64...`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a copy of WinHvPlatform.dll or it is not compatible with the later or earlier versions you are using (binary decoding error may resemble this symptom). Try going to the original git code and download this DLL file.
Hope it helps.
Arie

Comment: where can i download it?